# How to get all mouse events of an application?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to implement a screensaver on my application. Every time it's idle for some time, a video will be played over the app. To accomplish this, I'm using a QTimer that calls a function to play the video every 5 minutes. The problem is that I need to restart that timer with every user click. Currently I'm trying to connect all button clicks of my app with a restarter slot, but it's clearly not the best approach to accomplish this.
So, how can I grab all mouse events of the system to restart my timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install an [event filter](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) to the QApplication to receive all the events happening on the application

Comment: Yes, thats the best approach and works. The biggest problem is that if I filter the MousePress event, it does not propagate for all my Widgets. How can I solve this? Currently I made a workaround to reset the timer with every MouseMove, instead of MousePress.

Comment: Don't filter it, return false instead of true in eventFilter method

Comment: Also worth to mention, if your application won't be active it won't receive mouse events

Answer (score -1):

reimplement `bool QWidget::x11Event ( XEvent * event )` and you can receive system wide X events

Comment: Well it's only for X11, not for every platform solution

Comment: Not the most practical either